# Python - Why use anything other than uuid4() for unique strings?

Tags: python, unique, uuid

I see quit a few implementations of unique string generation for things like uploaded image names, session IDs, et al, and many of them employ the usage of hashes like SHA1, or others.

I'm not questioning the legitimacy of using custom methods like this, but rather just the reason. If I want a unique string, I just say this:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('07033084-5cfd-4812-90a4-e4d24ffb6e3d')
```

And I'm done with it. I wasn't very trusting before I read up on uuid, so I did this:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> s = set()
>>> for i in range(5000000):  # That's 5 million!
>>>     s.add(str(uuid.uuid4()))
...
...
>>> len(s)
5000000
```

Not one repeater (I wouldn't expect one now considering the odds are like 1.108e+50, but it's comforting to see it in action). You could even half the odds by just making your string by combining 2 `uuid4()`s.

So, with that said, why do people spend time on random() and other stuff for unique strings, etc? Is there an important security issue or other regarding uuid?

Comment: BTW, doubling the length of the uuid would square the number of possible values, not just double.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using a hash to uniquely identify a resource allows you to generate a 'unique' reference from the object. For instance, Git uses SHA hashing to make a unique hash that represents the exact changeset of a single a commit. Since hashing is deterministic, you'll get the same hash for the same file every time.

Two people across the world could make the same change to the same repo independently, and Git would know they made the same change. UUID v1, v2, and v4 can't support that since they have no relation to the file or the file's contents.

Comment: Objection!  UUIDs can in fact be deterministic!  UUIDv3 is based on an MD5 hash, and UUIDv5 is based on a SHA-1 hash.

Comment: One should pick UUIDv3 or UUIDv5 for deterministic things (uploaded files, git changesets, etc), and one should pick UUIDv1, UUIDv2, or UUIDv4 for transient, non-deterministic (sessions, temporary files, etc).

Comment: BTW git includes author info and commit date in change sets, so same changes by different people will not produce a same hash. The object files saved in `.git` folder is a valid use case though.

Answer (score 12):

Well, sometimes you want collisions.  If someone uploads the same exact image twice, maybe you'd rather tell them it's a duplicate rather than just make another copy with a new name.

Comment: @Ben, Wouldn't you just save the image name as another field in the row, and use programming logic to overwrite the existing image, or say "oops" when they upload the same image again.

Comment: His point is still valid: sometimes you want collisions, and GUIDs don't offer them.

Having said that, anyone who is using SHA-1 to find a *unique* string is probably doing something wrong, since its output is almost certainly less unique than its input.

Comment: @ladenedge I think the SHA1 is part of the equation just to make a more normalized value (in case there are spaces, etc).

Comment: @orokusaki: the image name is _generated_, according to the first line of the question.  So how is that going to help you identify duplicates, unless it's a hash on the content?

Comment: Here's my DB row `[image_name, image_filename, some_other_field, so_on_and_so_on]`. If I get a request to add a new image with an existing `image_name`, I just find the matching `image_filename` and replace that. Who would use the actual image file name for their system of record? I'm developing a multiple tenant architecture, so 5000 clients might have uploaded `logo.jpg`. I wouldn't rely just on having separate folders for each client because then if I change my file system to some cool new S3-like system I don't want to have to create new buckets for each client. That's a nightmare.

Answer (score 6):

One possible reason is that you want the unique string to be human-readable.  UUIDs just aren't easy to read.

Answer (score 3):

uuids are long, and meaningless (for instance, if you order by uuid, you get a meaningless result).

And, because it's too long, I wouldn't want to put it in a URL or expose it to the user in any shape or form.

Comment: Yeah, but that's what [shortuuid](https://github.com/stochastic-technologies/shortuuid) is for. All of the entropy, none of the longness.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, hashes are really good for things that should be immutable. The name is unique and can be used to check the integrity of whatever it is attached to at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Also note other kinds of UUID could even be appropriate.  For example, if you want your identifier to be orderable, UUID1 is based in part on a timestamp.  It's all really about your application requirements...